# Google Sheets - YNAB Progress Bars - Negative Value Colouring

Tags: google-sheets

I have the following in my Google Sheets:

[image]

Where H5 is the following:

```
=iferror(sparkline(F5:G5, {"charttype", "bar"; "color1", if(G5=F5, "72BE7A", "72BE7A"); "color2", if(G5<0, "FF0000", "808080"); "negcolor", "808080"}))
```

And where F5 = `=Iferror(D5/C5)`  and G5 = `=iferror(1-F5)`

This is working. However, occasionally, G5 will be greater than F5 (which I have in the code as `G5 <0` like so:

[image]

Where the red bar is meant to represent overspending. Unfortunately, whilst it is a 50% overspend, the bar is showing red at around 33% of the value.

I have messed around a lot, but I cannot seem to solve it. Any suggestions on where I am going wrong?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one approach:

when `Activity>Assigned` the card progress is maxed out at 1 (100%) and Missing becomes `-(Activity/Assigned)`

try:

**F5** : `=if(D5>C5,1,IFERROR(D5/C5))`

**G5** : `=if(D5>C5,-D5/C5,1-F5)`

[image]

Comment: Hey, thank you. That nearly works, however what I was hoping for is something like this:

If F5 was 100% and G5 was 0% then the bar would be fully green. If G5 was 150% the value of F5, then the bar would be half green and half red.

Comment: Actually I apologise. I think that is working correctly. I will indicate the percentage over as a text comment. Thank you Rock :)